# Is it possible to get notified on every 'Photos' access?

Tags: ios, photo

I'm trying to restrict access to iOS photo album from anywhere, or at least get notified when an app tries to access the photo album.

can it be done? 
(private api is also accepted)

Comment: So you want your app to be notified when any other app accesses the user's photo album?

Comment: yes, my phone, my permission to give, too many apps breach that trust.

Comment: Erm - unless jailbroken, using some private API - all apps require the user to grant permission to the user to access apps. At least iPhone - honestly, not sure on Android. I'm assuming not, since apps can send data in the future (future texting), but not entirely sure. I feel this counters your statement "too many apps breach that trust"

Comment: Not with only private APIs. With a jailbreak, you could reverse engineer the photo library and replace it with something that notified you, but this is not possible using an app. If you're interested in reverse engineering and modifying a jailbroken device, I would start at PhotoKit, and work my way down from there. The most obvious place to hook in would be PHAsset IMO.

Comment: Also, I would explore `assetsd`, which I believe provides the XPC hooks. Again, this would only be viable on a jailbroken device.